# Installation python-dev Issues

Tags: python, terminal, pip, winscp

I'm trying to install python-dev, setup tools and pip on Terminal in a server accessed via WinSCP. However, it keeps timing out.
I tried using `sudo apt-get install python-dev` and `apt-get install python2.7-dev` but both result in a timeout:

[image: time out]

Am I doing something wrongly or is the duration before the timeout kicks in too short (10 minutes)?

In addition, executing `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-pip` willl also result in a timeout. When I checked /usr/bin, i found

[image: /usr/bin]

So it seems like python is installed? But running `python --version` informs me no such command exists. However, running `python3 --version` returns **Python 3.6.7**. In addition, running `python -m pip --version`
 results in `-bash: line 98: python: command not found`

edit: Resolved all of this by logging in via Putty instead.

Comment: Did you try to install Python from a regular SSH terminal?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this but what do you mean

Comment: I mean an SSH terminal like PuTTY.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl you were right. After logging in via putty instead, all the commands ran smoothly.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just install from .exe, and add it to PATH's. https://www.python.org/getit/windows/ 
and try to install SublimeText3 and PyCharm for coding. Also you can use jupyter-notebook.